# function showDiv causing page to left justify on iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, centering

This is a weird question. I have one page that is centered via the same method all of my other pages are centered but ONLY on my iPhone, it has decided to left justify.

I narrowed it down to this line of code that is causing the problem:

```
<websitesnext><img src="graphic_elements/1-2.png" width="41" height="22" />&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="javascript:showDiv('websites2')"><img src="graphic_elements/next-icon.png" width="32" height="22" /></a></websitesnext>
```

That line is wrapped in a div titled "div id=websites", and is located just below a table. Here is the CSS for that wrapping div, and the CSS for the problem div:

```
#websites {
    position: absolute;
    top: 282px;
    left: 72px;
    width: 878px;
}

    websitesnext {
        position: absolute;
    left: 418px;
    width: 878px;
    top: 350px;
    z-index: 6;

}
```

Here is the javascript that that line is referencing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  //this is for the top gallery buttons
$(document).ready(function() {
            var option = 'websites2';
            var url = window.location.href;
            option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
            showDiv(option);
        });
        function showDiv(option) {
            $('.hidden').hide();   
            $('#' + option).show();
            $('#websites').hide();  //this hides the default gallery, which in this case is the first "websites" gallery page
    }
        </script>
```

I also noticed that again, just on this page, my viewport settings are being ignored! Any idea why this is causing ALL of my page contents to left justify on an iPhone? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is very hard to get a good cross platform design set-up by using absolute positioning.

Is it coming from a certain necessity, or just pure convince?.

Comment: @OlegTikhonov Well, it was the only way I could get that div to sit on the layer I wanted it to be, and in the position that I needed it in. The thing is, all of my pages use a ton of absolute positioning and those pages have zero issues. It's gotta be the javascript, but I'm not well versed enough in javascript to fully understand what is causing the glitch.

Comment: @Naomi Any chance you could post your dev url? There's no reason that JS snippet should left justify your page. You're just changing visibility.. Also have you tried setting the device width? http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/

Comment: @Mahdi.Montgomery I know right? It doesn't make sense to me. Imagine my frustration when I discovered that this section was the cause of my troubles.  The viewport code I am currently using which works on all the other pages is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />` no other viewport setting works for this page. The page with the issue is actually live at http://www.seednouveau.com/portfolio.html.